Replacing a transmission on 2008 nissan rogue awd
Could anyone on here confirm that a transmission from a 2011 nissan rogue and is compatible?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

I don't know for sure, but it looks like the transmissions from 2007 through 2015 interchange.
